# Why isn't the styling of my HTML document transfering when it is linked on another page?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML file and it is styled in another css file, which it is connected to. However, I connected the HTML file to another file (through a href), the styling did not transfer. Is there a solution to this other than styling in the same file?

```
  <li><a href = "index.html"> Needed Grade</a></li>
```

Here what the linked file looks like.

Comment: What do you mean by the "styling did not transfer"? Is the CSS not loading on the other page?

Answer (score 3):

CSS only applies to the HTML document that links to it. It doesn't apply to every page you visit thereafter. If it did, then (for example) every website you found through Google would have Google's stylesheet applied to it.

Put your CSS in a `.css` file. Put a `<link>` element that references that file in every HTML document you want to have that CSS applied to.